# Registrar em tabela caso a consulta retorne resultado (Oracle)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou desenvolvendo um painel de chamadas. Tenho uma query que resulta a chamada do cliente (nome/senha/guiche), essa query apresenta o resultado por 10 segundos, depois disso fica vazia até a próxima chamada.

Eu preciso que a cada vez que essa query tiver conteúdo (numrow>0), registre em uma outra tabela as informações. Assim, vou ter a informação dos últimos chamados do painel.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode criar uma procedure e nela colocar sua query e mais uma para inserir na outra tabela, você tem pode fazer a verificação na linguagem de programação  que está usando para fazer o painel.

Comment: Não bastaria consultar as 10 ultimas chamadas ? Algo como select * from (select nome,fone,datahora from chamada order by datahora ) where rownum <= 10